# How to get the hardware information of pc in AD domain

Tags: java, ldap

I know that information in LDAP can be read from client.but how i a get the hardware information of PCs  in AD domain,like CPU,memory and so on.

Comment: Which platform/Language you are using?

Comment: I have updated question to add java tag. I am not pretty much into java, might be someone else spot question now.